# Synchronising Async Redux actions for optimistic fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm building a product listing grid (like in an e-commerce site homepage) with Redux. The user can scroll infinitely and items are loaded from the server as they scroll. There is also a preemptive fetch during idle time, for the next batch of items.

I have modelled my redux actions (partially) as below:

- **FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST**: dispatched when a request is initiated
- **FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS**: dispatched when the earlier request was successful
- **LOAD_PRODUCTS**: dispatched when the user is scrolling to near page bottom, so the prefetched items can be loaded onto the DOM.

During an intermediate **LOAD_PRODUCTS**, I can set a timeout to dispatch **FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST** in order to preemptively fetch the set of items for the next batch.

However, I'm not entirely sure how to sync these actions on the initial page load (ie, when the ProductGrid component has mounted). I would ideally want to dispatch a **FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST** on component mount and then wait for the **FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS** to happen and then dispatch **LOAD_PRODUCTS**.

Considering the one way data flow in Redux, I'm not clear on how I can make sure the initial **FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS** has been fired (ie, my store has preemptive data) before I can dispatch a **LOAD_PRODUCTS** to render this data onto the DOM.

I'm using the *redux-saga* library to dispatch async actions.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They key here was that the `ProductGrid` component was aware if the `FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST` it was dispatching was an initialisation action (it happens inside `componentDidMount`). I added an `isInitial` flag as part of the action payload. The redux-saga middleware could then look at this value and then decide if a `LOAD_PRODUCTS` must be dispatched on receiving a `FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS` (this works because redux sagas are based on generators, so once the results are yielded by the async API, the saga can respond by sending the corresponding action(s) based on the action flag).

Answer (score 1):

A naive approach would be to store the initialization state of your application.

For example:

```
function initialized(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      return true;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This will be `false` when initially loading the page and switch to `true` after the first successful product request.

Comment: I went ahead with something similar, but instead of storing the state in the reducer the component being aware of the initial load (on component mount) can basically send this info as part of the action. The redux-saga middleware can then listen for FETCH_PRODUCTS_REQUEST and see if the initial load is set, and if so it can dispatch the LOAD_PRODUCTS after the FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS (the generators and pausing). Thanks anyhow!